# How to convert xml file to yaml?

Tags: ruby, xml, serialization, yaml

Basically questions says it all, how can I convert an xml file to yaml?

I've tried this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'
require 'yaml'

file = File.open("data/mconvert.xml", "r")
hash = Hash.from_xml(file.read)
yaml = hash.to_yaml
File.open("data/mirador.yml", "w") { |file| file.write(yaml) }
```

But, I am getting an "Exception parsing" error. I thought that was because I had dashes in an xml tag name, so I replaced the dashes with `dashcharacterr` But that still didn't work.

Comment: Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<-vikings->1336162202</-vikings-><panzara>1336162202</panzara><foggy_island>13361

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have a look at the XML 1.0 specification, we'll see that [start tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-stag) look like this:

```
[40]    STag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

and then elsewhere, we find [the definition of `Name`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar):

```
[4]     NameStartChar ::= ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a]    NameChar      ::= NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

You'll notice that `-` is not in `NameStartChar` so this:

```
<-vikings->1336162202</-vikings->
```

is not valid XML and this part of your code:

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(file.read)
```

is failing because your file doesn't contain XML, it contains text that looks like XML but isn't quite real XML.

Fix your `data/mconvert.xml` file to contain real XML and try again.

---

If you try a simple experiment in the Rails console, you'll see what's going on:

```
> Hash.from_xml('<-vikings->1336162202</-vikings->')
REXML::ParseException: #<REXML::ParseException: malformed XML: missing tag start
Line: 1
Position: 33
Last 80 unconsumed characters:
<-vikings->1336162202</-vikings->>
```

notice the "malformed XML: missing tag start"?